# "Are you hurt" vs. "Did you get hurt"

Tags: tenses, questions

What should we use when someone is injured?

> Are you hurt?

Or it should be

> Did you get hurt?

I felt using the second one as improper. Please correct me.

Comment: You might be interested in our sister site for [ell.se]

Comment: It depends on *when* the person was injured. Are you talking about a past incident, or in the present? Both forms could be acceptable and interchangeable, but under different circumstances one might be preferable over the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've amended the focus of the question to the auxiliary verb because it's not *hurt* which is being asked about: it's whether to use *Are you* or *Did you get* (or maybe its near-relative, *Were you*).

If someone is hurt at some indeterminate point in the past, then the question you ask says something about their **present** state. It doesn't matter how far in the past the injury occurred — it could be only seconds, or several days or longer.

- Are you hurt?
  → Were you hurt and are you **still** hurt?
- Did you get hurt?
  → Were you hurt at that point in the past?

Because the question "Are you hurt?" carries the implication of asking about the current situation (due to the use of the present tense), it really only makes sense to ask it if the injury is very recent, almost immediate.

Thus if you rush over to someone who has just fallen over, you would ask "Are you hurt?" rather than "Did you get hurt?" But if you know someone slipped on some ice last winter, you would ask "Did you get hurt?" because it's highly unlikely that they are still injured.

Note that "Did you get hurt?" requires that the time of the injury is in context. This might be done by the accident on the ice being the subject of the conversation, or being made contextual by adding it to the question: "Did you get hurt when you fell over last winter?"

Comment: Beat me to it; this answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks Andrew...that makes good sense when to use it....

Comment: This is a good answer, but you don't address the fact that, as well as a difference in tense, "are you hurt?" refers to a *state* whereas "did you get hurt?" refers to an *event*.

Comment: @starsplusplus "...the question you ask says something about their **present** state." "...you would ask 'Did you get hurt?' because it's highly unlikely that they are still injured."

Comment: @AndrewLeach The emphasis is on *present*, which implies that the other example says something about their **past** state (not, as is actually the case, a past *event*). The corresponding question asking about *past* state would be "Were you hurt?" not "Did you get hurt?"

Comment: I believe that everything you're saying is already in my answer. If you would like to post a better answer, please go ahead!